# Replace character and double quote and colon from json string using string.Replace?

Tags: c#, string

I am creating a json string using dictionary and I have to remove only that part from string my string is

```
[{Id: "code": "AAA" ,  Title: "display": "ANAA,FRENCH POLYNESIA"},{Id: "code": "AAB" ,  Title: "display": "ARRABURY, QL AUSTRALIA"}]
```

I want to remove only

```
"code":
```

And that part from string using string.Replace('', "")

```
"display":
```

I am trying this:

```
        var entries = dict.Select(d =>  string.Format("{{Id: {0} ,  Title: {1}}}", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
        return "" + string.Join(",", entries) + "";
```

Not working to achieve

```
[{Id: "AAA" ,  Title:  "ANAA,FRENCH POLYNESIA"},{Id:  "AAB" ,  Title:  "ARRABURY, QL AUSTRALIA"}]
```

Comment: Did you read the manual for `String.Replace`?

Comment: now see code editted what  i am doing is taking value from dictionary and making json but what i want to do is mention

Comment: from above json string at top screen i have given have "code":  and "display":  parts i have to remove this from string

Answer (score 1):

You can run this code:

```
 string json = "[{Id: \"code\": \"AAA\" ,  Title: \"display\": \"ANAA,FRENCH POLYNESIA\"},{Id: \"code\": \"AAB\" ,  Title: \"display\": \"ARRABURY, QL AUSTRALIA\"}]";
 json = json.Replace("\"code\":", String.Empty);
 json = json.Replace("\"display\":", String.Empty);
```

You can remove with replace method if you use **String.Empty**

Comment: only double quote like "val1" "val2"  between val1 and val2 "" have to be removed how

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, use string.Replace:

```
const string codeToRemove = "\"code\":";
const string displayToRemove = "\"display\":";
var entries = dict.Select(d =>  string.Format("{{Id: {0} ,  Title: {1}}}", d.Key.Replace(codeToRemove, ""), string.Join(",", d.Value.Replace(displayToRemove, ""))));
var result = "" + string.Join(",", entries) + "";
```

Comment: how to remove double quote only that thing left

Comment: only double quote like "val1" "val2"  between val1 and val2 "" have to be removed how